# Geforce digital vibrate not running

Tags: windows-7, display, nvidia-graphics-card

My new monitor doesn't seem to display with the right color settings by its own. Fortunately, Nvidia Control Panel seems to be able to solve the issue.

[image]

The problem is that whenever I start a game in 'full screen' mode and more important, whenever I start my PC these settings are not loaded and I need to switch settings at least once to make them work (like digital vibrance +1%).

Is there any way to load these settings automatically when Windows starts, and if possible reload them when going full screen as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to fix than what I had expected, by just changing `RGB` to `YcbCr444` it seems to display colours just fine automatically (even after restarting PC).

If anyone else is having this same issue, consider trying this first before moving to another solution, it may work to you as well.

[image]